# how to remove outliers from plotly interactive box plot

Tags: python-3.x, boxplot, outliers, plotly-python

I have the following interactive plot obtained from plotly.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(layout=go.Layout(height=2000, width=1000))
for i in rendimento_fondi.columns:
    fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=rendimento_fondi[i], name=i))
fig.layout.title.text = "Box Plot: Performance vs # Fondi selezionati per la Monte Carlo"
fig.show()
```

which generate this
[image]

what I want is to remove the outliers, so that they are not shown.
Can anybody help?

Comment: If you have a dataset that has a specific range (which does not include the outliers), you could try and set the minimum and maximum x values so that it doesn't show the outliers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I found an option for managing outliers.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=rendimento_fondi[i], name=i, boxpoints = False))
```

here is the reference

https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/